# Adding a Note to a Contact in SugarCRM via REST

Tags: rest, sugarcrm

I was able to Create a Contact via the REST API. I was also able to create Notes and upload files to them. It's not clear to me how to use the REST API to add the Note to the Contact either at creation time or after the fact. How would I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

You can set parent_type = Contacts and parent_id =  on creating the note.

Or you use the endpoint

https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_9.0/Integration/Web_Services/REST_API/Endpoints/modulerecordlink_POST/